# How can I Mock OpenSearch Client in Django unit test

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, elasticsearch, opensearch

I'm trying to mock **OpenSearch** client for writing unit tests for those methods using OpenSearch operations i.e. index, delete, etc. I have tried *openmock* library's decorator but in git workflow test it couldn't connect to **OpenSearch** client.